# CDK Add HTTPS to Elastic Beanstalk Application Load Balancer Python

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

Is there a way to use CDK to configure an HTTPS listener in an Application Load Balancer for Elastistic Beanstalk ? I can't make a ALB without an the EB's associated AutoScalingGroup, so it doesn't seem like I can create it before the EB. It seem like if I could, I can use the custom LB option in EB to a reference the ALB that was created in a previous step.

Answer (score 0):

```
        eb.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty(
            namespace='aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment',
            option_name='LoadBalancerType',
            value='application'
             ),
        eb.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty(
             namespace='aws:elbv2:listener:443',
             option_name='ListenerEnabled',
             value='true'
             ),
        eb.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty(
             namespace='aws:elbv2:listener:443',
             option_name='SSLCertificateArns',
             value=certificate_arn
         ),
        eb.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty(
             namespace='aws:elbv2:listener:443',
             option_name='Protocol',
             value='HTTPS'
         )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**